# Access Google Drive from Ruby with PEM file

Tags: ruby, drive

I currently access Google Sheets using the Node module edit-google-spreadsheet, which takes as one of the authentication options, an email address and a PEM file (converted/encrypted P12 file?), which doesn't require input from the user (typical OAuth flow).

I'd like to do the same in Ruby, but I can't find a way to do it.  This is a service account accessing a configuration document, it's not applicable to have a user going through an OAuth flow.

Can anyone give me some guidance here?

Thanks!